# Images not aligning correctly when using For Loop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm making a sticker page with various different sizes of an image.
The sticker needs to be within the orange circle which is 1000px in radius.

[image]

To ensure the alignments are correct, I added a test black border to visually see how it will be laid out.

[image]

This was how it was laid out. It's beautiful.

[image]

So, I thought the script was ready. I put it to work but now without the black borders. This was how it turned out...

[image]

See how it's cropped at the bottom right corner? I feel its something to do with the 'Math' of my For Loop codes which I can't figure out...
Here are my codes:

```
    // Page 3: Third document. =====================================================
    // Note: Need to re-initialize as the variables are referencing to the previous document.
    //       Error shown: The requested action requires that the target document is the frontmost document.
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var layer = doc.activeLayer;
    // Get the variables to work with.
    var width       = doc.width.as('px');
    var height      = doc.height.as('px');
    var bounds      = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;
    var layerWidth  = bounds[2].as('px') - bounds[0].as('px');
    var layerHeight = bounds[3].as('px') - bounds[1].as('px');
    var resolution  = doc.resolution;

    // Create bleed guides.
    doc.guides.add(Direction.HORIZONTAL, bleed);
    doc.guides.add(Direction.VERTICAL, bleed);
    doc.guides.add(Direction.HORIZONTAL, height - bleed);
    doc.guides.add(Direction.VERTICAL, width - bleed);

    // Third auto-page workings.
    // x1 biggest.
    doc.paste();  // Paste the selection.
    doc.activeLayer.translate(0 - width / 4, 0 - height / 4);  // Move layer to the top left corner. First copy.
    var big_copy = doc.activeLayer;  // Copy the selection.
    // x4 mid sized.
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            copy = doc.activeLayer.duplicate();
            copy.translate(0 + width / 4 * i, (0 + height / 2) + (height / 4 * j));
            copy.resize(50, 50, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
        }
    }
    // Many minis.
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            copy = big_copy.duplicate();
            copy.translate((0 + width / 2) + (width / 2 / 3 * i), 0 + (height / 6 * j));
            copy.resize(100 / 3, 100 / 3, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
        }
    }

    doc.artLayers.getByName('Background').remove();  // Delete the Background layer.
    mergeVisible();  // Merge visible.
    freeTransform(0, 0, (width - bleed * 2) / width * 100, (height - bleed * 2) / height * 100);  // Resize selection within bleeds.
```

Edit: [More info] The black border is merged with the dino image before the automation. So, I'm guessing why it's working correctly with the border was because the merged image had a 1000px by 1000px in dimension. The moment I removed the black borders, it broke. It could be due to the anchor position... But I'm not sure.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample psd file and a working example of code: it'd be much easier to find a problem.

Comment: Hi Sergey! You've helped me a lot man. But... this script is being done for a client. I asked my partner and he's not ok. I can only share the working codes that are causing the issue. I've updated my question with more info if it helps...

Comment: I understand this and I don't ask for a full script. But at the moment if I run the sample on a random image I'm getting errors and the end result looks nothing like the one you're getting: and spending time on fixing an example isn't something I want to do.. Maybe someone else would though. Just cut all the parts that aren't needed (like removing background and merging all) and make sure that the script runs on its own.

Comment: I understand really sorry about that... Here are the PSD and stripped-down version of the script: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/igewuqah7p5n0eh/AAA8sS30h-MbtrcFCLbrgXMja?dl=0. Run the script with the border layer turned on and off and you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little: partly the issue was that the script was merging all the visible layers and when some of the layers were outside document bounds they weren't the part of this merge. So

- on line 67 I create a group to contain all the layers
- on lines 75, 86 and 97 all the duplicates are added to that group
- on line 105 instead of `mergeVisible()` I select the group and merge it down with `mergeDown()`
- and then a tad later for free transform I use bounds of this new layer

Here's the result:

[image]

and the code:

```
var maintainAspectRatio; // Set to true to keep aspect ratio.
maintainAspectRatio = true;
if (app.documents.length > 0)
{
    app.activeDocument.suspendHistory('Auto Sheet Maker', 'AutoSheetMaker(' + maintainAspectRatio + ')');
}

function AutoSheetMaker(keepAspect)
{ // keepAspect:Boolean - optional. Default to false.
    // Store the ruler.
    var defaultRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    // Global bleed pixels on all docs.
    bleed = 25;

    // Main master document. =======================================================
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var layer = doc.activeLayer;
    // Get the variables to work with.
    var width = doc.width.as('px');
    var height = doc.height.as('px');
    var bounds = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;
    var layerWidth = bounds[2].as('px') - bounds[0].as('px');
    var layerHeight = bounds[3].as('px') - bounds[1].as('px');
    var resolution = doc.resolution;

    // The saved directory location of the main master document.
    Path = doc.path; // If the document is new there is no doc.path. Error is shown.

    // Main master document workings.
    copy = doc.layerSets["Artwork"].duplicate(); // Duplicate Group layer by name.
    doc.activeLayer = doc.layerSets["Artwork copy"]; // Select Group layer by name.
    doc.activeLayer.merge(); // Merge the selection. In this case, the Group layer.
    var dogbox = 1000; // The region dimensions that's considered in the automation.
    ellipse_selection(height / 2 - dogbox / 2, width / 2 - dogbox / 2, width / 2 + dogbox / 2, height / 2 + dogbox / 2); // Make a circle selection.
    freeTransform(0, 0, width / dogbox * 100, height / dogbox * 100); // Resize selection to fit the whole canvas, ignoring bleeds.
    doc.selection.copy(); // Copy the selection.
    deSelect();
    doc.artLayers.getByName('Artwork copy').remove(); // Delete the Artwork copy layer.

    // =============================================================================

    app.documents.add(width, height, resolution, "layout_debug", NewDocumentMode.CMYK); // Create a new document.

    // Page 3: Third document. =====================================================
    // Note: Need to re-initialize as the variables are referencing to the previous document.
    //       Error shown: The requested action requires that the target document is the frontmost document.
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var layer = doc.activeLayer;
    // Get the variables to work with.
    var width = doc.width.as('px');
    var height = doc.height.as('px');
    var bounds = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;
    var layerWidth = bounds[2].as('px') - bounds[0].as('px');
    var layerHeight = bounds[3].as('px') - bounds[1].as('px');
    var resolution = doc.resolution;

    // Create bleed guides.
    doc.guides.add(Direction.HORIZONTAL, bleed);
    doc.guides.add(Direction.VERTICAL, bleed);
    doc.guides.add(Direction.HORIZONTAL, height - bleed);
    doc.guides.add(Direction.VERTICAL, width - bleed);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // new: creating a group to contain all the layers
    var layersGroup = doc.layerSets.add();

    // Third auto-page workings.
    // x1 biggest.
    doc.paste(); // Paste the selection.
    doc.activeLayer.resize(50, 50, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER); // Resize the pasted layer by 50%.
    doc.activeLayer.translate(0 - width / 4, 0 - height / 4); // Move layer to the top left corner. First copy.

    doc.activeLayer.move(layersGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE); // new: adding active layer to the group

    var big_copy = doc.activeLayer; // Copy the selection.
    // x4 mid sized.
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            copy = doc.activeLayer.duplicate();
            copy.translate(0 + width / 4 * i, (0 + height / 2) + (height / 4 * j));
            copy.resize(50, 50, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
            copy.move(layersGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE); // new: adding active layer to the group
        }
    }
    // Many minis.
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            copy = big_copy.duplicate();
            copy.translate((0 + width / 2) + (width / 2 / 3 * i), 0 + (height / 6 * j));
            copy.resize(100 / 3, 100 / 3, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
            copy.move(layersGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE); // new: adding active layer to the group
        }
    }

    doc.artLayers.getByName('Background').remove(); // Delete the Background layer.

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // new: selecting the group and merging it down
    doc.activeLayer = layersGroup;
    mergeDown();

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // new: getting coords of the resulting merge layer to transform those
    var bounds = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;
    var layerWidth = bounds[2].as('px') - bounds[0].as('px');
    var layerHeight = bounds[3].as('px') - bounds[1].as('px');

    freeTransform((-bounds[0].as('px') + bleed), (-bounds[1].as('px') + bleed), (layerWidth - bleed * 2) / layerWidth * 100, (layerHeight - bleed * 2) / layerHeight * 100); // Resize selection within bleeds.

    // =============================================================================

    // Restore the ruler.
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = defaultRulerUnits;

    alert("Script automation completed!");
}

// Ellipse marquee selection.
function ellipse_selection(top, left, right, bottom)
{
    var id1 = charIDToTypeID("setd");
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id2 = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var id3 = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var id4 = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    ref1.putProperty(id3, id4);
    desc1.putReference(id2, ref1);
    var id5 = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id6 = charIDToTypeID("Top ");
    var id7 = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc2.putUnitDouble(id6, id7, top); //top
    var id8 = charIDToTypeID("Left");
    var id9 = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc2.putUnitDouble(id8, id9, left); //left
    var id10 = charIDToTypeID("Btom");
    var id11 = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc2.putUnitDouble(id10, id11, bottom); //bottom
    var id12 = charIDToTypeID("Rght");
    var id13 = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc2.putUnitDouble(id12, id13, right); //right
    var id14 = charIDToTypeID("Elps");
    desc1.putObject(id5, id14, desc2);
    var id15 = charIDToTypeID("AntA");
    desc1.putBoolean(id15, true);
    executeAction(id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO);
}
// Deselect selection.
function deSelect()
{
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID("setd");
    var desc19 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref5 = new ActionReference();
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var idfsel = charIDToTypeID("fsel");
    ref5.putProperty(idChnl, idfsel);
    desc19.putReference(idnull, ref5);
    var idT = charIDToTypeID("T   ");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idNone = charIDToTypeID("None");
    desc19.putEnumerated(idT, idOrdn, idNone);
    executeAction(idsetd, desc19, DialogModes.NO);
}
// Free transform ('Ctrl' + 't' method).
function freeTransform(top, left, width, height)
{
    var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID("Trnf");
    var desc92 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref23 = new ActionReference();
    var idLyr = charIDToTypeID("Lyr ");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
    ref23.putEnumerated(idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt);
    desc92.putReference(idnull, ref23);
    var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID("FTcs");
    var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID("QCSt");
    var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID("Qcsa");
    desc92.putEnumerated(idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa);
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID("Ofst");
    var desc93 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID("Hrzn");
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc93.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idPxl, top);
    var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID("Vrtc");
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
    desc93.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idPxl, left);
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID("Ofst");
    desc92.putObject(idOfst, idOfst, desc93);
    var idWdth = charIDToTypeID("Wdth");
    var idPrc = charIDToTypeID("#Prc");
    desc92.putUnitDouble(idWdth, idPrc, height);
    var idHght = charIDToTypeID("Hght");
    var idPrc = charIDToTypeID("#Prc");
    desc92.putUnitDouble(idHght, idPrc, width);
    var idIntr = charIDToTypeID("Intr");
    var idIntp = charIDToTypeID("Intp");
    var idbicubicSharper = stringIDToTypeID("bicubicSharper");
    desc92.putEnumerated(idIntr, idIntp, idbicubicSharper);
    executeAction(idTrnf, desc92, DialogModes.NO);
}
// Merge visible layers.
function mergeVisible()
{
    var idMrgV = charIDToTypeID("MrgV");
    executeAction(idMrgV, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
}

function mergeDown()
{
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Mrg2'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of mergeDown()
```

Comment: Ahh so sorry I didn't see this cos I was preparing the docs for you. But I don't think 'merge down' will fix it.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code and the file: it was much simpler to test the workflow. I edited my answer with a solution.

Comment: No problem :) I had a quick test. But even if the picture without the black border is no longer cropped, the placement is different compared to when the black border layer is turned on. So, when I swap out the dino's pic with something that only covers a small portion of the orange circle, running the automation gives it a completely different placement (but not cropped, which is good). The problem now is the placement is not standardized and gives it varied placement positions due to the bounds of the sticker image.

Comment: The placement is different between border and borderless layers because borderless layers have transparency that's not considered in bounds, so bounds values are different. If you need them to be the same, add a white background or white 1px stroke with 1% opacity or include the difference in bounds between border/borderless layers in your calculations

Comment: Yes, that's what I eventually did but using 5px instead :)